# How do I plot the x axis line using Highcharts when pegged at 0?

Tags: highcharts

How do I plot the x axis line for a bar chart pegged at 0, like when you have positive and negative values (i.e. bars on both side of X axis)?

Answer (score 1):

It is not different than plotting a normal column chart. Just use negative values and Highcharts will scale the chart automatically.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Column chart with negative values'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5]
    }]
});
```

**jsFiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8LLto4dL/)**

Comment: Thanks @Emre for your reply! I don't want grid lines to appear on the chart. I am creating this bar chart inside HTML table rows (<tr> tag). For some reasons, the vertical line (x-axis) is not drawn on 0 and rather is drawn on left side of the highest negative value.

Comment: Can you please create a jsFiddle? It is hard to solve your problem without seeing the code.

Comment: Thanks @Emre for your quick reply. Here is what I have - https://jsfiddle.net/y433y4vL/ 
To give you background, I have an HTML table. Each row has one of this bar chart. All values on separate rows collectively make it look like a bar chart spanning across the table with positive and negative values. Max and Min values on Y-axis are dynamic, but same for all the charts in the table. I have set them -100 and +100 just as reference here. My problem is that the X-axis line is not plotted on the left side of the bar here. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yes, but I need the X axis line to touch the left edge of the bar that is @ Y = 0.

Comment: This example may help to you: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-negative-stack/